# How to create a set of distinct integers that sum up to zero but all other subsets do not

Tags: number-theory

For any arbitrary size $k$, can we create a set of integers that sum up to zero but all other subsets do not? If this possible, what would the upper bound of integers be?

Comment: yes right. Why couldn't I think of that..

Comment: $\{1,2,\ldots,k-1,-\binom{k}{2}\}$ works.